# I have written test class for this trigger where code is not covered at acc.adderror line?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

[image]

```
Test Class:
@istest
public class Practice_All_in_One_TestClass{
static testmethod void Practice_All_in_One_TestClass()
{
account acc=new account(Description='ggg');
insert acc;
account acc1=new account(name='cccc');
insert acc1;
contact con=new contact(lastname='ccccc',accountid=acc1.id);
insert con;
opportunity opp=new opportunity(name='cccc',stagename='cccc',closedate=date.today(),accountid=acc1.id);
insert opp;
account acc3=new account(name='ccccc',id='xxx');
account acc3_1=[select id,name from account where id=:acc3.id];
delete acc3_1;
} 
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: need to cover 100% code coverage

Comment: need to cover adderror line

Comment: Seeing  some extra curly braces after last 'for loop' (red, uncovered)  what are these meant for ?  Check by any chance  if  you've included loop inside  if trigger.new  condition.

Comment: @frezsfdc - What is your test class actually testing? There is no point in what you have written at all as All you are doing is covering lines of code. Test code that covers lines of code will never be valuable as the users will see these types of issues immediately (a line causes an error) issue before any test class could. You should be, in addition, testing any outcomes, business login, etc. using system asserts. An "AllInOne" test class is an extremely bad example of how to write test methods...If you are just learning, keep in mind that this is NOT what a test class should be

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues that jump out:

```
account acc=new account(Description='ggg');
insert acc;
```

This part should fail due to at least one required field missing "Name" on account.

```
account acc3=new account(name='ccccc',id='xxx');
```

The above line should fail for attempting to give acc3.Id the value of 'xxx'

```
account acc3_1=[select id,name from account where id=:acc3.id];
```

This line will also fail since acc3 was never inserted so you should get the no rows for assignment error.

```
delete acc3_1;
```

This line is probably where you need to get in order to cover what it appears you are trying to cover in your trigger, with the code you currently have in your test, you can probably save it but not sure you can run it without it failing.